# Remote file copy with powershell from multiple servers and rename

Tags: powershell, copy, rename

new to this community and new to powershell.
I have been tasked to collate a file from each one of our files servers.

I need to copy this file and then have it renamed to the name of the server it came from.

I have figured out this so far;

```
$ListOfServers = Get-Content "C:\Temp\TEST.txt"
Copy-Item "\\$ListOfServers\c$\utils\TSM\baclient\dsmsched.log" -Destination "C:\temp\Testtest.txt"
```

in my TEST.txt file i have a list of servers to copy the file from but when i put in more than one server name it does not copy the file from them, when i take the TEST.txt file back to one server it does copy ok. also i would like to rename the LOG file i am extracting to the name of the server it came from.

Any help here would be more than appreciated.

Thanks in advance. MV

Answer (score 0):

When you put more than one servername in the file, `$ListOfServers` is an array of names (lines of the file, really).

When you put an array inside a string with `"$a"` syntax, the contents get strung together with a space between them, so your copy becomes `"\\server1 server2 server3\c$\utils\.."` and doesn't work.

You need to use a loop, e.g.

```
Get-Content "C:\Temp\TEST.txt" | ForEach-Object {

    Copy-Item "\\$_\c$\utils\TSM\baclient\dsmsched.log" -Destination "C:\temp\Testtest-$_.txt"

}
```

The loop variable `$_` is the line / server name, and I also put the server name in the destination filename too.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you are trying to describe. I personally usually put something like this in a for loop, but I'm not entirely sure it's necessary. You definitely need a unique destination if you want to keep a file from each server, and you are not doing that. You can handle the rename in your destination.
Try setting -destination to c:\temp\$serverfromforloop-testtest.txt